# How to replace values with NULL of all column's start with "stage{col's}" when condition statisfied

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scenario, where the final dataframe looks like below which was the result of Joining stage and foundation.

```
+-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|ID_key             |ICC_key                 |suff_key       |stage_{timestamp}      |stage_{code}|stage_{dol1}|stage_{dol2}|final_{timestamp}      |final_{code}|final_{dol1}|final_{dol2}|
+-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|222                |222                     |1              |2019-02-02 21:50:25.585|9123        |20.00       |1000.00     |2019-03-02 21:50:25.585|7123        |30.00       |200.00      |
|333                |333                     |1              |2020-03-03 21:50:25.585|8123        |30.00       |200.00      |2020-01-03 21:50:25.585|823         |30.00       |200.00      |
|444                |444                     |1              |2020-04-03 21:50:25.585|8123        |30.00       |200.00      |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
|555                |333                     |1              |null                   |null        |null        |null        |2020-05-03 21:50:25.585|813         |30.00       |200.00      |
|111                |111                     |1              |2020-01-01 21:50:25.585|A123        |10.00       |99.00       |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
+-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

i am looking for a logic,  on each row when final_{timestamp} > stage_{timestamp}, have to replace the value with "null" all the column starts with stage_{}.

Like below:

```
+-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|ID_key             |ICC_key                 |suff_key       |stage_{timestamp}      |stage_{code}|stage_{dol1}|stage_{dol2}|final_{timestamp}      |final_{code}|final_{dol1}|final_{dol2}|
+-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|222                |222                     |1              |null                   |null        |null        |null        |2019-03-02 21:50:25.585|7123        |30.00       |200.00      |
|333                |333                     |1              |2020-03-03 21:50:25.585|8123        |30.00       |200.00      |2020-01-03 21:50:25.585|823         |30.00       |200.00      |
|444                |444                     |1              |2020-04-03 21:50:25.585|8123        |30.00       |200.00      |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
|555                |333                     |1              |null                   |null        |null        |null        |2020-05-03 21:50:25.585|813         |30.00       |200.00      |
|111                |111                     |1              |2020-01-01 21:50:25.585|A123        |10.00       |99.00       |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
+-------------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

It would be great if you can help me with the logic.
"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
// Select all stage columns from dataframe
val stageColumns = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("stage"))

// For each stage column nullify unless condition satisfied
stageColumns.foldLeft(df) { (acc, c) =>
  acc.withColumn(c, when('final_timestamp <= 'stage_timestamp, col(c)).otherwise(lit(null)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

**Condition**

```
scala> val expr = col("final_{timestamp}") > col("stage_{timestamp}")
```

**Condition `Matched` Columns**

```
scala> val matched = df
                      .columns
                      .filter(_.startsWith("stage"))
                      .map(c => (when(expr,lit(null)).otherwise(col(c))).as(c))
```

**Condition `Not Matched` Columns**

```
scala> val notMatched = df
                         .columns
                         .filter(!_.startsWith("stage"))
                         .map(c => col(c).as(c))
```

**Combining `Not Matched` & `Matched` Columns**

```
scala> val allColumns = notMatched ++ matched
```

**Final Result**

```
scala> df.select(allColumns:_*).show(false)
+------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|ID_key|ICC_key|suff_key|final_{timestamp}      |final_{code}|final_{dol1}|final_{dol2}|stage_{timestamp}      |stage_{code}|stage_{dol1}|stage_{dol2}|
+------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|222   |222    |1       |2019-03-02 21:50:25.585|7123        |30.00       |200.00      |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
|333   |333    |1       |2020-01-03 21:50:25.585|823         |30.00       |200.00      |2020-03-03 21:50:25.585|8123        |30.00       |200.00      |
|444   |444    |1       |null                   |null        |null        |null        |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
|555   |333    |1       |2020-05-03 21:50:25.585|813         |30.00       |200.00      |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
|111   |111    |1       |null                   |null        |null        |null        |null                   |null        |null        |null        |
+------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

pyspark solution :

```
#test_data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(867,0.12,'G','2020-07-01 17-49-32','2020-07-02 17-49-32'),(430,0.72,'R','2020-07-01 17-49-32','2020-07-02 17-49-32'),(658,0.32,'A','2020-07-01 17-49-32','2020-06-01 17-49-32'),\
                                              (157,0.83,'R','2020-07-01 17-49-32','2020-06-01 17-49-32'),(521,0.12,'G','2020-07-01 17-49-32','2020-08-01 17-49-32'),(867,0.49,'A','2020-07-01 16-45-32','2020-08-01 17-49-32'),
                                              (430,0.14,'G','2020-07-01 16-45-32','2020-07-01 17-49-32'),(867,0.12,'G','2020-07-01 16-45-32','2020-07-01 17-49-32')],
                                               schema=['stage_1','stage_2','RAG','timestamp','timestamp1'])
# change the string column to date
tst_format= (tst.withColumn('timestamp',F.to_date('timestamp',format='yyyy-MM-dd'))).withColumn('timestamp1',F.to_date('timestamp1',format='yyyy-MM-dd'))
# extract column information with name 'stage' and retain others
col_info =[x for x in  tst_format.columns if 'stage_' in x]
col_orig = list(set(tst_format.columns)-set(col_info))
# Build the query expression
expr = col_orig+[(F.when(F.col('timestamp1')>F.col('timestamp'),F.col(x)).otherwise(F.lit(None))).alias(x) for x in col_info]
# execute query
tst_res = tst_format.select(*expr)
```

The results are :

```
+---+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|RAG|timestamp1| timestamp|stage_1|stage_2|
+---+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|  G|2020-07-02|2020-07-01|    867|   0.12|
|  R|2020-07-02|2020-07-01|    430|   0.72|
|  A|2020-06-01|2020-07-01|   null|   null|
|  R|2020-06-01|2020-07-01|   null|   null|
|  G|2020-08-01|2020-07-01|    521|   0.12|
|  A|2020-08-01|2020-07-01|    867|   0.49|
|  G|2020-07-01|2020-07-01|   null|   null|
|  G|2020-07-01|2020-07-01|   null|   null|
+---+----------+----------+-------+-------+
```